# How to List all functions in a *.so C library

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04

Just created a *.so library that contains some functions. How can i see all the functions it contains.I have tried to view the content but all i see is some garbage.

Comment: Try `nm -DC yourlib.so`. Add `--defined-only` for obvious effect.

Comment: Do you want to see all the functions or only those which are exported and so directly callable?

Comment: I would love to see all functions and if possible programatically like using some C header files to write a program that does this.

Comment: `nm` does this programmatically (how else)? Crack open its source code and study.

Answer (score 4):

```
nm -o

man nm
nm - list symbols from object files
```

Comment: Thanks and  would live to know if it can be done programatically like using a c program?